# How to perform drop() using MongoDB drivers for php 7?

Tags: php, mongodb

How to perform drop() or remove() and other functions by using MongoDB drivers for php 7?

I refered
https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/js-collection/

but, I am not getting much documentation for PHongo (MongoDB driver for PHP 7).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you seen http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php and http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocollection.php

Comment: Yes. Above link is mongodb documentation for php 5. I want to do for php 7. i.e. PHongo

Answer (score 6):

You can delete a collection like this:

```
$manager = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://" . $username . ":" . $password . "@{$host}:{$port}");
$manager->executeCommand('database', new \MongoDB\Driver\Command(["drop" => "collection"]));
```

or you could follow the instructions in [this guide](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/classes/database/#dropping-collections):

```
$db = (new MongoDB\Client)->demo;

$result = $db->dropCollection('users');
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Using `MongoDB\Driver` is wrong. Unless you are writing a driver yourself, no application code should be using that. The "this guide" link in the answer is in fact the only correct part.

Comment: @NeilLunn I was under the impression the Client is deprecated (see http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php) and am thus currently working on a Manager based implementation.
Can you shed some light on your comment?

Comment: @BartGloudemans You are under the wrong impression, and that's perfectly understandable since I have personally complained about this now for years. The thing you "think" is deprecated in the old `mongo` driver. The actual driver implementation to use ships in **two** parts, and this clearly confuses a lot of people. Ask the actual maintainer and he will keep pointing to http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.overview.php which shows the "composer" installed part as the bit you need to be using. That's what the doc link above actually points to.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks! That clarified a lot